# How to make OData pick RestEasy as provider?

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, wildfly-8, odata4j

We have a RestEasy-based JAX-RS application serving URLs to clients that now has a requirement to call another API that uses OData4j. When I tried to use ODataConsumer in this application to consume the response from the other API, I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.provider.RuntimeDelegateImpl 
    cannot be cast to org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory
```

None of the methods specified in results from google search seem to solve the issue. Before reaching this point, it was complaining that Jersey could not find Jackson and I made Jackson JARs available as providedCompile (use Gradle). Is this problem happening because the OData4j is trying to use Jersey as provider while my application is already using RestEasy. I understand that RestEasy and OData4j integration is not easy.

Is there a way for OData4j to be made to pick RestEasy and not Jersey as I think it will solve this issue?